# Is this switch installed correctly, and is it safe?

Tags: electrical, switch

I installed this switch myself as it was a simple job. Can someone tell me if everything looks okay  with this installation? The switch is working, I just want to make sure I didn't do anything obviously wrong.

[image]

[image]

Comment: We can't possibly say without either a better view or some description of the _connections_, which are the critical pieces here.

Comment: ...is that red wire connected to the green screw?!?!

Comment: @maples  Do agree picture is at a bad angle, but OP said switch was working and if connected to ground, breaker would be tripping.  Probably close but no cigar.

Comment: The grounding is correct, the switch automagically picks up ground from the grounded metal box via the mounting screws.  By the way, better quality receptacles which are labeled "self-grounding" can do that same trick.  Small reward for paying $4 for a receptacle.  (GFCIs too).

Answer (score 5):

It looks like your wires are into "backstab" connections. They should be under the screws. The backstab connections are legal (if they weren't, they wouldn't be there) but they are one-time use (so no remove/adjust/replace) and are more prone to failure than a well-done screw connection.